# Cannot open database file error when running on AWS lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm using coinmarketcap in my program, and I've properly installed the library into a deployment package that i've uploaded to my aws lambda function. However, even though the code works locally on my machine, it returns the following error message when run on aws lambda:

```
{
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/main.py",
      11,
      "lambda_handler",
      "return on_intent(event[\"request\"], event[\"session\"])"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/main.py",
      50,
      "on_intent",
      "data = coinmarketcap.ticker('Bitcoin', limit=3, convert='USD')"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/coinmarketcap/core.py",
      54,
      "ticker",
      "response = self.__request('ticker/' + currency, params)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/coinmarketcap/core.py",
      28,
      "__request",
      "response_object = self.session.get(self.base_url + endpoint, params = params, timeout = self.request_timeout)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/coinmarketcap/core.py",
      21,
      "session",
      "self._session = requests_cache.core.CachedSession(cache_name='coinmarketcap_cache', backend='sqlite', expire_after=120)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/requests_cache/core.py",
      68,
      "__init__",
      "self.cache = backends.create_backend(backend, cache_name, backend_options)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/requests_cache/backends/__init__.py",
      50,
      "create_backend",
      "return registry[backend_name](cache_name, **options)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/requests_cache/backends/sqlite.py",
      28,
      "__init__",
      "self.responses = DbPickleDict(location + extension, 'responses', fast_save=fast_save)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/requests_cache/backends/storage/dbdict.py",
      58,
      "__init__",
      "with self.connection() as con:"
    ],
    [
      "/usr/lib64/python2.7/contextlib.py",
      17,
      "__enter__",
      "return self.gen.next()"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/requests_cache/backends/storage/dbdict.py",
      70,
      "connection",
      "con = sqlite.connect(self.filename)"
    ]
  ],
  "errorType": "OperationalError",
  "errorMessage": "unable to open database file"
}
```

Code:

```
Was Here
```

Any Idea as to why this would be happening?

Comment: Can you explain more what is the code trying to do? I can see you are using an SQLite file as the database, but do you only read from it or also write?

Comment: The code is pretty basic. I'm retrieveing the prices of a cryptocurrency (the type being dependent on the intent name) using coinmarketcap and then returning a speechlet response. So just reading

Comment: Can you please share your code, or at least that part of it?

Comment: Just added the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coinmarketcap-api code (take a look [here](https://github.com/mrsmn/coinmarketcap-api/blob/master/coinmarketcap/core.py#L21)) fails when trying to create a local file called `coinmarketcap_cache.sqlite` in `/var/task/` (you will find it on you local machine, what's why it works locally).

AWS Lambda doesn't have write access to `/var/task/`. However, it has write access to`/tmp/`. Sadly the coinmarketcap-api doesn't support changing the location of that file, this leaves you with very little options:

Try changing the current directory at VERY TOP of your code.

```
import os
os.chdir("/tmp")
```